# Crash on some devices when using GCD

Tags: crash, grand-central-dispatch

I have an iOS application that's crashing on a few devices. Given the bad reviews I see left on iTunes when this happens, the crashes appears to be happening at the same point in the code.

Finally, one nice person actually contacted me instead of just leaving a review, and they even when as far as to install a debug version of the app using TestFlight for me.

Armed with the crash report I can see that it occurs somewhere deep in malloc:

```
2 libSystem.B.dylib 0x34683d6e _sigtramp + 42
3 libSystem.B.dylib 0x3468c886 szone_malloc_should_clear + 2122
```

And, given the line number, it appears to happen at the point that I start a background task:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    UIImage *image = [self loadImage:path];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

I'm unsure which of those 3 lines the crash is happening on, so it's unclear if the crash occurs at the call to GCD itself, right at the start of the block's code, or somewhere in the block itself.

The stack trace ends up in the function which includes the code snippet above and not, it would seem, in the block itself. If the crash were in the async block, would the stack trace still include the call tree to the parent function? I'm currently working o n the assumption that the stack trace for crash inside the block wouldn't include the call the the parent function (since the block's being executed asynchronously in its own thread), so I think it's the call to GCD that's crashing.

I've tried using TFLog to find the exact moment of failure, but the logs aren't being recorded at all. I know the log calls are done correctly since on my development device I see the logs pop up in the TestFlight recorder, so it seems that the crash is perturbing this debug option.

Finally, TestFlight can't find an iOS version number for the iPhone 4 that this user's using - so I'm wondering if this is a Jailbroken device, and if it is could that possibly have an effect? (I've asked the user, no answer yet).

Note that this is all ARC code, so i'd be very surprised to discover that it's a memory management issue. It's also isolated to a few devices, but those devices crash at the same point every time.

Can anyone offer any insights or debugging suggestions (given that I don't have a crashing device myself).

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this horrid bug.

It turns out that DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND is only available on 5.0 or later, and will crash on previous versions.

I had actually tested the app on an iPhone 3G running 4.2.1, but since that model doesn't support GCD at all that particular code path wasn't being run....